# how to make a drum rack instrument (boom kick) to be a separate playable midi-track

Tags: ableton-live

Beginner question here:

Let's say I have a drum rack with a 808 boom kick in it.

I want to be able to play this boom kick on my midi controller keyboard, meaning instead of one note I have in the drum rack -> I want the sound to be "propagated" with corresponding pitch modifications to the notes on my keyboard.

Preferably, I want a new midi track with this new "808 boom" instrument.

I tried to do it via automation -> pitch change, but it is kinda complicated and I want to be able to play each note on my keyboard.

What am I missing out?

Comment: You need the note to be mapped to more than one Midi note. That will depend on what you're using for your sampler.

Comment: I agree, I need to "stretch" this single note in the drum rack to all notes on my keyboard with the appropriate pitch change. how do I do it?

Comment: https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/instrument-drum-and-effect-racks/#18-5-zones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drum rack is design to use only one note per instrument. If you want more than one note for one of the instruments in the drum rack, one easy way is to click to select the sampler that contains the instrument from inside the rack, then control-click (command-click for mac) and drag a copy of it into another track, like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]